# Script to add hyperlink when pre-defined text is found?

Tags: php

I'm using PHP to pull some data from an google calendar XML feed, and I'm wondering if there's any kind of script that will run after this and if it finds a certain phrase (not a URL), add a hyperlink to it?

E.g. if it pulls "Bayerische Staatsoper" from the feed it will add a hyperlink for the Staatsoper website.

Is this possible?

Hope that makes sense.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
str_replace("Bayerische Staatsoper","<a href='#'>Bayerische Staatsoper</a>",$text);
```

The above code searches for "Bayerische Staatsoper" in variable `$text` and replaces it with the link.